# Reading files stored in an Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, file, directory

this is a little hard to explain, I want to be able to read from some files which I have on my computer in an iOS app. I am storing the files in the same directory as my 'ViewController.swift' file.

[image]

My question is, if I want to read from the file "testData.csv", how should I go about referencing it in my app?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
let file = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("testData", ofType: "cvs")
var contents = String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)!
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let bundlePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("testdata", ofType: "csv")
var textContent = String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)!
println(textContent)
```

To make the code generic and reusable, You can define a function which accepts your file name as well file type.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Get file URL

```
let fileUrl = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("testData", withExtension: "csv")
```

Then you can parse the file using this swift lib 
https://github.com/naoty/SwiftCSV